# Is there an interceptor pattern for sequelize for tokenizing & detokenizing sensitive data to/from db

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I am using sequelize for postgres and need to tokenize across tables for chosen fields to tokenize and detokenize before storing and after retrieving respectively.

Any suggested best practices where I can do this at a single place rather than doing this @ every model's create/update/ get hooks?

I am looking for something like an interceptor pattern that can be used for all models at one at the sequelize instance level. is that possible?

Comment: I guess using beforeQuery and afterQuery hooks could help.. Will check and confirm.

Comment: beforeQuery and afterQuery both are executed before hitting the db. there is no hook available for being called after db returns the results.. Or is there one?

Answer (score 0):

The feature you are looking for, sounds like `getter` & `setter` for properties of sequelize Model. You can declare model with custom `getter` & `setter` like following.

```
const YourModel = sequelize.define("ModelName", {
    secretData: {
        type : //Data type
        set(value) {
            // do what ever processing you want to applied, which will be stored in db
             this.setDataValue("secretData", PROCESSED_VALUE)
        }
        get() {
             const storedValue = this.getDataValue("secretData")
             // do whatever processing you want to applied, on storedData
             return processedData
          }
    }
}
```

Comment: nope. If it was a model level I could have gone with that. But we need it for all models.  A hook to be called after db returns records....

Comment: @ubreddy - were you able to find a solution?